# Create new instance of Campaign in every iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on functionality whereby a table is displayed with records, each with radio buttons Reject and Approve. A user selects the appropriate radio button and presses process. Control is passed to process_campaigns. From here it breaks down the data and analyses each record's status. If it is approved it redirects to approve block and same with reject.

The following parameters are passed:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9TCExvCmDahAWGQloPdaRkSowbBaxZGwZnRa8sbNkWM=", "campaign"=>{"2"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-18 15:43:00", "end_date"=>"2016-10-15 12:20:00", "merchant_revenue"=>"10", "status"=>"Approved", "notes"=>""}, "1"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-15 12:20:00", "end_date"=>"", "merchant_revenue"=>"10", "status"=>"Approved", "notes"=>""}}, "Commit"=>"Process"}

def process_campaign
  authorize! :operator, current_user.operator 
  params[:campaign].each do |key, value|
    if value[:status] == "Approved"
      redirect_to approve_operator_campaign_path(key), :id => key, :start_date => value[:start_date], :revenue_mode => value[:revenue_model], :end_date =>  value[:end_date], :active => true, :status => 307 and return 
    elsif value[:status] == "Rejected"
      redirect_to reject_operator_campaign_path(key), campaign_name: key, notes: value[:notes], :status => 307 and return 
    end
  end
  redirect_to operator_campaigns_path, flash: { notice: "Campaigns have been processed."}
end

def reject
  authorize! :operator, current_user.operator
  params[:campaign].each do |key, value|
    if value[:status] = "Rejected"
      @campaign = Campaign.active.where(id: key, operator_id: current_user.operator_id).last!
      @campaign.data.merge!({:notes=>value[:notes]})
      @campaign.status = "Rejected"
      @campaign.save(validate: false)
    end
  end
end

def approve
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
  params[:campaign].each do |key, value|
    if value[:status] = "Approved"
      @applied_campaign = AppliedCampaign.new(:campaign_id => key, :start_date => value[:start_date]||Time.now, :end_date =>  value[:end_date], :active => true)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is when control is passed to approve or reject the entire campaign string is passed with both records contained within whereas I want to seperate each record and pass it individually. Can anyone indicate why the entire campaign string is being passed?

Answer (score 0):

Move the params inside the route helper

```
redirect_to approve_operator_campaign_path(key, param_1: 1, param_2: 2)
# Parameters: { "id"=>"2" "param_1"=>"1", "param_2"=>"2" }
```

Change your method to:

```
def process_campaign
  authorize! :operator, current_user.operator 
  params[:campaign].each do |key, value|
    if value[:status] == "Approved"
      redirect_to approve_operator_campaign_path(key, id: key, start_date: value[:start_date], revenue_mode: value[:revenue_model], end_date:  value[:end_date], active: true, status: 307) and return 
    elsif value[:status] == "Rejected"
      redirect_to reject_operator_campaign_path(key, campaign_name: key, notes: value[:notes], status: 307) and return 
    end
  end
  redirect_to operator_campaigns_path, flash: { notice: "Campaigns have been processed."}
end
```

Comment: Thanks but its now saying `No route matches [GET] "/operator/campaigns/2/reject"` but i want to POST/PUT to that path. What would I need to change?

Comment: check for the path generated using rake:routes

Comment: for post/put on approve action of operator_campaigns controller

Comment: Have the following in rake routes 
`approve_operator_campaign POST       /operator/campaigns/:id/approve(.:format)                                         operator/campaigns#approve
                       reject_operator_campaign POST       /operator/campaigns/:id/reject(.:format)                                          operator/campaigns#reject`

Comment: Then it should work or you can add { method: :post } param there

Comment: like this ---- approve_operator_campaign_path(key, param_1: 1, param_2: 2, method: :post)